# How to replace parse_args arguments?

Tags: python

I have downloaded a python script made of three files:

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
```

I usually call the script with a command like:

```
python file1.py arg1 arg2 -n arg3 arg4
```

Now I would like to call this script from within another python file, file4.py, but I don't know how I should provide the arguments.

In file1.py I have:

```
import time
import file2
import file3

def main():
    variable1, variable2, variable3 = file2.parse_args()
    ...
    run_simulation(variable1, variable2, variable3)

def run_simulation(variable1, variable2, variable3):
    ...
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and file2.parse_args() is something like:

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Desc1")
    parser.add_argument("variable1", nargs="*", type=str,
                        help="Help")
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--byte", nargs="*", type=str, metavar="byte",
                        help="Help2")
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--exact", action="store_true",
                        help="Help3")
    # Parse command line arguments and check for errors
    args = parser.parse_args()
    error_check_arguments(args)

    [...]
    variable1, variable2 = None, None
    if not args.input:
        variable1, variable2 = parse_cards(args.variable1, args.variable2)
    return variable1, variable2, variable3
```

so what code should I put in file4.py to be able to run this script as if I was running it from the command line?

Comment: what is `file2.parse_args`?

Comment: @MSeifert it's a function in file2.py that defines and parses possible command line arguments (the arguments formatted like -n arg3 arg4 )

Comment: @https://pypi.python.org/pypi/canonicaljson/  please include its code.  If however it's from the argparse module, take a look at the python documentation; you can simply pass in new arguments to it.

Comment: Also include the line where `args` is assigned.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I have added this line

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the file 2's argument parsing capability and are simply wishing to pass the arguments from calling file 1 to a function in file 4 then a tuple seems Pythonic.  So this code could be added to file 1:

```
import sys
import file4


# skip the first item which is the files name
arguments = tuple(sys.argv[1:])
file4.function_to_be_called(arguments)
```

Comment: I would like to keep file2's argument parsing capability if possible

Answer (score 0):

Change the `main` function so that it takes the variables as arguments.

```
def main(variable1, variable2m variable2):
    ...
```

Move the code that parses the args to the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    variable1, variable2, variable3 = file2.parse_args()
    main(variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

You can now call the `main` function from a different module:

```
from file1 import main
main('variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3')
```

Comment: But if I do that I'm losing file2's argument parsing capabilities, right? I need to know beforehand what variable1, variable2 and variable3 are, whereas I would like to keep the command line flexibility, sometimes passing one argument, sometimes 3...

Comment: In that case you should make the variables optional, and set defaults in the `main` function. The key point is that if you want `main` to be reusable, you should move the argument parsing outside of it.